# Accessing view using Robotium - CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, automation, robotium, black-box-testing

I am trying to access a search bar of my app using the `id` and then entering search text and submit but as I try to grab the view, my test case fails and throws Exception:

Adding full logs

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5932)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:873)
at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4253)
at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10663)
at android.widget.TextView.invalidateRegion(TextView.java:4609)
at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:4552)
at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:7434)
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:9130)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:979)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:688)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:302)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3777)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3647)
at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3622)
at com.expedia.search.test.SearchActivityTester.testAllCountries(SearchActivityTester.java:48)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

Below is my code :

```
View searchBar = solo.getView("search_edit_text"); //get the element
searchBar.performClick(); //click on search bar
solo.sendKeys("My Search Query"); //enter my query
solo.sendKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH);  //hit search on softkeyboard
```

I am new to automation testing for Android so have no idea. Please suggest.
Also if the above method I am using is right enough to do the job or not?

Here is my test class

```
public class SearchActivityTester extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {

private static final String LAUNCH_ACTIVITY_NAME = "com.my.aut.activity.SearchActivity";

private Solo solo;

private static Class<?> splashActivityClass;
static {
    try {
        splashActivityClass = Class.forName(LAUNCH_ACTIVITY_NAME);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public SearchActivityTester() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    super(splashActivityClass);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

public void testAllCountries() {
        solo.sleep(7000);
        solo.clickOnText("Countries");
        Log.d("clicked", "clicked on hotels");
        solo.sleep(2000);
        View searchBar = solo.getView("search_edit_text"); //get the element
           searchBar.performClick(); //click on search bar
           solo.sendKeys("My Search Query"); //enter my query
           solo.sendKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH);  //hit search on softkeyboard


        List<ListView> list = solo.getCurrentViews(ListView.class);
        Log.d("****************", list.get(1).getId()+"");

        solo.sleep(3000);
}


@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();

}

 }
```

Comment: Generally this error occurs whenever you try to access a View item from Thread code.

Comment: I am unable to get this "Thread code" as to why the error? Obviously a thread would run when i launch my test case so ultimately view is being fetched from thread only. So how to fix it?

Comment: Also when I change the code to access EditText rather than a View, it shows it cannot find the EditText with the id. The code is 
`EditView searchBar = solo.getEditText("com.my.aut.R.id.search_bar_id")`

Answer (score 2):

Try to integrate this code to your code:

```
private StackDemo mActivity;

public SearchActivityTester() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    super(splashActivityClass);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    mActivity = this.getActivity();
}

public void testAllCountries() {
    solo.sleep(7000);
    solo.clickOnText("Countries");
    Log.d("clicked", "clicked on hotels");
    solo.sleep(2000);

    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            View searchBar = solo.getView("search_edit_text"); //get the element
            searchBar.performClick(); //click on search bar
        }
    });



    solo.sendKeys("My Search Query"); //enter my query
    solo.sendKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH);  //hit search on softkeyboard


    List<ListView> list = solo.getCurrentViews(ListView.class);
    Log.d("****************", list.get(1).getId()+"");

    solo.sleep(3000);
}


@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();

}

}
```

Comment: As I said, its blackbox and I don't have source code of the AUT so can't import its MainActivity class.

Comment: In setup you use this mActivity = this.getActivity(); so you get the mainActivity

Comment: But what about the compile time error ? Like "create class StackDemo"

Comment: Could you show me the complete java code and the error log?

Comment: I have just one Test class which i already there in the question. It is not allowing me to create any mActivity instance due to compile time error. And i guess logs are also there in the question.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what class are you extending (usually `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`) for your unit tests you should be able to call

```
getActivity()
```

and on the returned object you can call `runOnUiThread` to make changes to the UI.

you might want to give [it](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html#UITesting) a look

Comment: `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` is the super class. I am trying to find a way to access the search bar which is nothing but EditView and be able to fill up my search query and hit search key.

Comment: if it is the super class, that means that you are extending it. That means that you can call getActivity

Comment: Actually, its blackbox testing. I don't have the source code so i can't import MainActivity class of my AUT

Comment: can you post your testing class?